# Simplest way to share credentials across multiple servers

Tags: environment-variables, digital-ocean, soa

I know this is a common problem, but after searching quite a bit I don't have a solution that I like. I am creating a simple Service Oriented Architecture example for my students. We are using Digital Ocean. There will be three separate servers who need to find out each other's IP addresses and various secret tokens (e.g. Twitter access tokens). I want to illustrate the idea that one does not put such info into the code repo.

My plan is to use environment variables in all the strategic spots. But how to get those environment variables set up "automatically" and "maintainably"?

1. I could have a private github repo with just one file and remember to clone it and update it on all three servers
2. I don't want to get into capistrano and similar complicated things
3. I thought of having a gist with the information in it and using http to grab it but gists are public. Ok I make the gist private but now I have to authenticate that gist and I am back where i started.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever path you choose, you will have to provide a means of authenticating accessing to the secrets.

Either "I've written the Twitter access token on the white board"

Or "the secrets are stored in a service and here's how you authenticate access to them".

For the latter, a private Git repo is not the worst solution. You could provide access to the repo to your students(' accounts). They would have a 2-step: acquire token from GitHub repo, apply token to Digital Ocean resource.

Alternatives exist including HashiCorp's [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) see [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-securely-manage-secrets-with-hashicorp-vault-on-ubuntu-16-04). I recently used Google's [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) too. These are 3rd-party services rather than features provided by Digital Ocean directly.

I suspect that there's an implicit question in *simplifying* the process too which would entail delegated auth. There may be a way (though I'm unaware of it) to delegate auth to Digital Ocean such that you can provide a mechanism (similar to the above examples) that's contrained to specific Digital Ocean accounts.